# vb.net complex if statement

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I have a program where I use a complex if statement.  The below if statement doesn't process correctly:

If the textbox1.text on form3 has data in it, it never processes the first else statement, it acts as if it exits the sub.  Now, if the form3 textbox1.text is blank, it processes the messagebox if statement exactly how its written.  Whats wrong with the below if statement?

```
 If form3.TextBox1.Text = "" Then
   Dim result1 As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Click OK to fill out user settings, or CANCEL to do it later", "Settings", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
   If result1 = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
      pwauthen.ShowDialog()
   ElseIf result1 = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
      Exit Sub
   Else
     If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
       MsgBox("Please describe the issue you're having Bender, I'm not a mindreader!")
       Exit Sub
     Else
     .......Do a lot of other processing.....
     End if
   End if
 End if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this look right? The formatting should help you. When you click on one of the elements of the If statement will will highlight all the parts to show you where they belong.

```
If form3.TextBox1.Text = "" Then
    Dim result1 As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Click OK to fill out user settings, or CANCEL to do it later", "Settings", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
    If result1 = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        pwauthen.ShowDialog()
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please describe the issue you're having Bender, I'm not a mindreader!")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        '.....Do a lot of other processing.....
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm counting correctly, the last end if closes that first if.  The first if doesn't have an else block.  The else block would be immediately before the end if.

Let Visual Studio help,with indenting.  That usually makes the code easier to read.  You can also hover over if statements to see the end (at least for c++ and c#, haven't used VB in awhile)